# Google generated and matplotlib graphs are different

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to find a curve of best fit using the following code:

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit(lambda t,a,b: a+b*np.log(t), data_list, noise_data, absolute_sigma=True)
```

The parameters returned are [-51.90326506, 13.77241918], ie:
y = -51.90326507 + 13.77241918*log(x)

Plotted on MatPlotLib, the results look like the following:

[Results plotted on matplotlib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3KCr.png)

However, the same equation plotted on Google's graphs looks like the following:

[Results plotted on Google's graph tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOjmW.png)

I use the code below to generate the curve of best fit:

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit(lambda t,a,b: a+b*np.log(t), data_list, noise_data, absolute_sigma=True)

curvex=np.linspace(min(data_list), max(data_list))
p1 = popt[0]
p2 = popt[1]
curvey=(lambda x,c,m: m*np.log(x)+c)(curvex,p1,p2)

# plot data
plt.plot(data_list,noise_data,'x',label = 'Xsaved')
plt.plot(curvex,curvey,'r', linewidth=2, label = 'Model')
```

Why does this disparity exist? Is python right or are google's maps correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because by default google graphs uses log to the base `10`, but numpy uses log to the base `e` as default.

By explicitly using log to the base `10` with numpy we can recreate the plot that google gave us:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a = -51.9
b = 13.8

x = np.linspace(0, 175000)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=[10, 4])

# Use log to the base 10 to create google's plot
ax[0].plot(x, a + b*np.log10(x))
ax[0].set_title('Base 10 log (google default)')

# Log to the base e is the numpy default
ax[1].plot(x, a + b*np.log(x))
ax[1].set_title('Base e log (numpy default)')

fig.tight_layout()
```

This gave me the following plot:

[image]